# How to Download dependencies when auditing a hardhat project?

Tags: solidity, web3js, erc-20, hardhat, foundry

I just attempted to audit smart contracts that were tested using the Hardhat framework. In Foundry, after cloning the repository, I know that I can install all the necessary dependencies by simply using the 'forge test' command. However, in Hardhat, I'm not sure how to install the dependencies. Can anyone please explain how I can do that?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check if it used yarn or npm, then run either `npm install` or `yarn install`. After installing run the test command `npx hardhat test ./test/TestFilePath`.

Comment: yeah,I tried with npm install but the terminal throws the below errors and im using the node.js version of v18.15.0.
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: @venusprotocol/venus-protocol@4.0.0-dev.1
npm ERR! Found: solidity-coverage@0.8.5
npm ERR! node_modules/solidity-coverage
npm ERR!   dev solidity-coverage@"^0.8.4" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer solidity-coverage@"^0.7.21" from @nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox@1.0.2

Comment: Below is the installation process provided in readme file
```
git clone https://github.com/code-423n4/2023-09-venus       cd 2023-09-venus                                                                          yarn install # or `npm install`

```

Comment: what about `yarn install`?

Comment: i haven't pre installed yarn in my laptop

Comment: Then install it, it will work fine

Comment: yeah,its working Tq

Comment: cool, can you mark this as an answer :)